# ModuleNotFoundErro--but I was already importing it

Tags: python-3.x, macos, beautifulsoup, cron

I'm trying to run a cron job from my local machine using crontab. The file I'm trying to run is working without error when run manually from the command line.

The job looks pretty much like this:

`01 13 * * * cd path/to/file && echo 'password' | sudo -S /usr/bin/python3 filename.py > log.txt 2>&1`

Here's the error I was getting:

```
Password:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "contractsfinder.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scraper_functions import *
  File "</path/to/file>/my_functions.py", line 3, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

The file `my_functions.py` is just where I keep all my import requests in a central document accessed by a number of other python scripts. I am importing a number of modules. There is no issue with loading any of the modules when I am running this script manually.

I saw on another post somewhere that I should try to add: `from urllib import requests` which I did, and that got rid of the original error saying 'no module named requests'. However, now I'm getting a new error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'`

Trying the fix that worked for requests doesn't work for bs4 because there is no library to import it from, or at least I don't think there is. Previously I had just used `import bs4`.

So, obviously when I am running the file this way, something different needs to happen with the importing of modules. But when I did `pip3 list` earlier I saw both bs4 and requests were in there all along.

What do I need to do differently to get these modules to import correctly?

Comment: Hi. Can you run sudo -H pip install bs4 and try running the cron again?

Comment: @rahul1205 This gives me some `Requirement already satisfied` messages and then running the cron again gives me the same error.